# C++ QThread for Oscilloscope/LAN communication

Tags: c++, qt

I have written a Class for LAN communication using an Agilent Oscilloscope.

I would like you to your opinion what I can change with this code, so it work without problem.

I would like to know your opinion, how I write this code better and efficiently.

I would like to change this class maybe with the VISA exchange.
What do you say?

I would like to rewrite this class because the communication with the Osziloscope takes a lot of time

This class is for LAN Communication:

**Header File:**

```
class QTcpSocket;

class CAgilentLan : public QThread
{

public:

typedef enum 
{
    enRspTimeout = -2, 
    enRspOffline,
    enRspOK,
    enRspError
} t_enRspType ;


CAgilentLan(QString strIpAdress_p, int iTimeout_p, bool boSimulate_p=false, bool boDebug_p=false);
~CAgilentLan();

// High-Level Funktionen
QByteArray ExecuteGetScreenshot(void);
void ExecuteSaveScreenshot(QString &strPathFileName_p, const char *strFormat_p);
void ExecuteSettingsSave(unsigned char ucRegisterNo_p);
void ExecuteSettingsRecall(unsigned char ucRegisterNo_p);
double ExecuteQuickMeasure(unsigned char ucChannel_p, char *pchType_p);
double ExecuteStatMeasure(char *pchType_p, bool boTrigger_p);
void ExecuteResetMeasurementStatistics(void);

bool Open(const QString &strIpAdress_p, const int iTimeout_p);
bool Close(const int iTimeout_p);
t_enRspType Execute(const char *strCmd_p, const int iWaitResponse_p, const int iTimeout_p, const int iRspDelayed_p);
QByteArray GetLastResponse(void);

t_enRspType ExecuteSimulated(const char *strCmd_p);
QString GetAgilentIdentifikation();

...

 protected:
void run();

private:
bool m_boDebug;
bool m_boSimulate;

QMutex m_MtxProcess;
QMutex m_MtxResponse;

QWaitCondition m_WaitCondProcess;
QByteArray m_ByteArrayWrite;
QByteArray m_ByteArrayRead;

QByteArray m_IDN_AgilentIdentification;

//Hilfsvariable
double m_SDDevPeriodeA ;
double m_SDDevDCA;
double m_SDDevDCB;
double m_SDDevWidthZ;

double m_OZiSDDevPeriodeA;
double m_OZiSDDevDCA;
double m_OZiSDDevDCB;
double m_OZiSDDevWidthZ;

double m_OZiMeanPeriodeA;
double m_OZiMeanDCA;
double m_OZiMeanDCB;
double m_OZiMeanWidthZ;

QByteArray m_ByteSTDD;
QByteArray m_ByteMean;
QStringList m_ListSTDDev;
QStringList m_ListMean;

QTcpSocket *m_pTcpSctCtrl;

QString m_strCtrlIP;
int m_iTimeoutClose;
int m_iTimeout;
int m_iResponseDelayed;
int m_iWaitResponse;

t_enRspType m_enRetVal;
};
```

**Cpp File:**

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
CAgilentLan::CAgilentLan(QString strIpAdress_p, int iTimeout_p, bool boSimulate_p, bool boDebug_p):m_SDDevPeriodeA(0),   m_SDDevDCA(0),m_SDDevDCB(0),m_SDDevWidthZ(0)
 {
//  boSimulate_p = false;

m_boDebug = boDebug_p;
m_boSimulate = boSimulate_p;

m_enRetVal = enRspOffline;
m_strCtrlIP = QString("");
m_iTimeout = 0;
m_iTimeoutClose = iTimeout_p;
if (this->Execute("CreateObject", 0, 0, 0) != enRspOK)
{
    throw(QString("Error AgilentLan.CPP/Constructor TcpSocket Create memory error"));
}

this->Open(strIpAdress_p, iTimeout_p);
 }
  /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/

 CAgilentLan::~CAgilentLan()
{
while(isRunning());

this->Close(m_iTimeoutClose);

while(isRunning());

if (this->Execute("DeleteObject", 0, 0, 0) != enRspOK)
{
    throw(QString("Error AgilentLan.CPP/Destructor TcpSocket Delete memory error"));
}


while(isRunning());
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
  bool CAgilentLan::Open(const QString &strCtrlIP_p, const int iTimeout_p)
{
bool boRet_l = true;

m_strCtrlIP = strCtrlIP_p;

if (this->Execute("OpenConnection", 0, iTimeout_p, 0) != enRspOK)
{
    throw(QString("Error AgilentLan.CPP/Open TcpSocket Open Connection error"));
}

if (m_boDebug)
{
    throw(QString("Tcp Socket is open"));
}

return boRet_l;
}
 /*----------------------------------------------*/

  bool CAgilentLan::Close(const int iTimeout_p)
{
 bool boRet_l = true;

while(isRunning());

if (this->Execute("CloseConnection", 0, iTimeout_p, 0) != enRspOK)
{
    throw(QString("Error AgilentLan.CPP/Close Connection error"));
}

if (m_boDebug)
{
    throw(QString("Tcp Socket is closed"));
}

while(isRunning());

return boRet_l;
 }
  /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/

   CAgilentLan::t_enRspType CAgilentLan::Execute(const char *strCmd_p,     const int iWaitResponse_p, const int iTimeout_p, const int iRspDelayed_p)
 {
 CAgilentLan::t_enRspType enRetVal_l = enRspOffline;

if (!isRunning())
{
    m_ByteArrayRead.clear();

    m_ByteArrayWrite.clear();
    m_ByteArrayWrite.append(strCmd_p);

    m_iWaitResponse = iWaitResponse_p;
    m_iTimeout = iTimeout_p;
    m_iResponseDelayed = iRspDelayed_p;

    start();

    m_MtxProcess.lock();
    m_WaitCondProcess.wait(&m_MtxProcess,-1);
    m_MtxProcess.unlock();

    enRetVal_l = this->m_enRetVal;
}
else
{
    enRetVal_l = enRspError;
}

while(isRunning());

return enRetVal_l;
}
 /*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
QByteArray CAgilentLan::GetLastResponse(void)
 {
QByteArray ay_l;

m_MtxResponse.lock();
ay_l = m_ByteArrayRead;
m_MtxResponse.unlock();

return ay_l;
 }
 /*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 void CAgilentLan::run()
{
bool boRun_l = true;
bool boSent_l = false;

const char *pStrCmd_l = NULL;
const char *pStrRsp_l = NULL;

m_enRetVal = enRspError;

if (strcmp(m_ByteArrayWrite.data(),"CreateObject")==0)
{
    if (this->m_boSimulate == true)
    {
        m_enRetVal = enRspOK;
    }
    else
    {
        m_pTcpSctCtrl = (QTcpSocket *)new QTcpSocket;
        if (m_pTcpSctCtrl != NULL)
        {
            m_enRetVal = enRspOK;
        }
    }

    boRun_l = false;
}

if (strcmp(m_ByteArrayWrite.data(),"DeleteObject")==0)
{
    if (this->m_boSimulate == true)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_pTcpSctCtrl != NULL)
        {
            delete m_pTcpSctCtrl;
        }
    }

    m_enRetVal = enRspOK;
    boRun_l = false;
}

if (strcmp(m_ByteArrayWrite.data(),"OpenConnection")==0)
{
    if (this->m_boSimulate == true)
    {
        m_enRetVal = enRspOK;
    }
    else
    {
        m_pTcpSctCtrl->connectToHost(m_strCtrlIP,5025);
        if (m_pTcpSctCtrl->waitForConnected(m_iTimeout) == true)
        {
            m_enRetVal = enRspOK;
        }
    }

    boRun_l = false;
}

if (strcmp(m_ByteArrayWrite.data(),"CloseConnection")==0)
{
    if (this->m_boSimulate == true)
    {
        m_enRetVal = enRspOK;
    }
    else
    {
        m_pTcpSctCtrl->disconnectFromHost();
        if ((m_pTcpSctCtrl->state() == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState) || (m_pTcpSctCtrl->waitForDisconnected(m_iTimeout)))
        {
            m_enRetVal = enRspOK;
        }
    }

    boRun_l = false;
}

int iTimeout_l = m_iTimeout;

while (boRun_l && (!this->m_boSimulate))
{
    if (boSent_l == false)
    {
        boSent_l = true;
        // Kommando absetzen
          m_pTcpSctCtrl->write(m_ByteArrayWrite.data(),m_ByteArrayWrite.size());
        // Auf Antwort warten
        if (m_iWaitResponse >= 0)
        {
            QThread::msleep(m_iWaitResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            boRun_l = false;
        }
    }

    // Anwort auf Kommando abwarten 
    if ((m_pTcpSctCtrl->bytesAvailable() > 0) && (boRun_l == true))
    {
        m_MtxResponse.lock();

        m_ByteArrayRead.append(m_pTcpSctCtrl->readAll());

        if (m_boDebug)
        {
            throw(QString(m_ByteArrayRead.data()));
        }

        m_MtxResponse.unlock();

        iTimeout_l = m_iTimeout;
        //iTimeout_l = m_iWaitResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_pTcpSctCtrl->waitForReadyRead(iTimeout_l) == false)
        {
            m_MtxResponse.lock();

            if (m_ByteArrayRead.size() == 0)
            {
                if (m_boDebug)
                {
                    throw(QString("AgilentLan Timeout"));
                }
                m_enRetVal = enRspTimeout;
            }
            else
            {
                m_enRetVal = enRspOK;
            }

            m_MtxResponse.unlock();

            boRun_l = false;                    
        }
    }
}

QThread::msleep(m_iResponseDelayed);

QMutexLocker locker(&m_MtxProcess);

m_WaitCondProcess.wakeOne();

}
}
 /*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't need to prefix calls to member functions or access to member variables with `this->`.

Answer (score 3):

You indentation is not consistent, I'll presume that is a paste error. If not then please fix that, it's much easier to see where functions begin and end when the signature and closing brace stand out.

If you inherit from a QObject like QThread you should add the Q_OBJECT macro as the first thing in the definition this will provide access to the signal-slots mechanism os Qt.

However **don't inherit from QThread**. You don't need to.

Instead you create a QObject subclass with some slots to receive the results and use `QtConcurrent::run` to so actual processing.

If the bulk of the wait time is actual waiting on communication then use the async capabilities of QTcpSocket.

Comment: If I am describing this class: How should I change this then please step by step?

Comment: @user3860708 step 1: read a tutorial on Qt signal slots system. step 2: map out the lifetime of this class and what signals it needs to send out and what slots it needs to receive. step 3: use what you learned in step 1 to implement step 2.

Comment: A short question: Do you know VISA "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Instrument_Software_Architecture"
What do you say when I integrate this class into VISA?
I do not have to write the connection to the Oscilloscope myself and thus the connection and the communication is much quickly

Comment: @user3860708 - that link is broken (stray `"`).

Comment: VISA is : Virtual Instrument Software Architecture

Answer (score 0):

## Don't subclass `QThread`

Please read [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) by Maya Posch.  You should not need to inherit from `QThread`; instead, create your runnable object and move it into a thread.

## Don't busy-wait

This repeated code snippet is a resource hog:

```
while(isRunning());
```

Instead of repeatedly testing the state of the thread, you'll want to reorganise your code so that its interaction is all via signals.